# Updating Location header does not affect redirect

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'm trying to update the Location header. I can see the new value for the header in the Console, however the browser is not redirecting to the new URL.

Here's my manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Hello Extensions",
    "description": "Base Level Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "action": {
    "default_popup": "hello.html",
    "default_icon": "hello_extensions.png"
    },  
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "scripts/background.js"
      },
    "host_permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "permissions": [    
    "webRequest"
    ]
}
```

background.js:

```
var callback = function(details) {
    if (details.statusCode === 302) {
        
        var locationHeader = details.responseHeaders.find(x => x.name === 'Location')
        if (locationHeader) {       
            locationHeader.value = "https://www.google.com";
            console.log(details);
        }
    }
    
    return { responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders };
}

var filter = { urls: ["*://*/*"] };

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(callback, filter, ["responseHeaders"]);
```

Here you can see the new value for Location:

[image]

I also had a look in the tab's own Console and can see the Location value has not persisted.

How can I make the browser redirect to the new Location header value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `webRequestBlocking` permission for that (and the accompanying `'blocking'` mode in addListener), but it's allowed only in a policy-installed ManifestV3 extension (or in a patched/recompiled Chrome binary), otherwise `webRequest` API is purely observational, i.e. it can't make changes.

There's no solution for normal ManifestV3 extensions until [crbug.com/1141166](https://crbug.com/1141166) is fixed, then you'll be able to use [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/declarativeNetRequest) API to change the header on responses that already have it.

The current workaround is to use declarativeNetRequest unconditionally for the domains that you confirmed to serve this header. To list the domains in one rule you can use `requestDomains` array or just omit `condition` altogether in case the list is the same as `host_permissions` in manifest.json.

Comment: What is "policy-installed ManifestV3 extension" and how can I convert my code to use that?

Comment: Are you able to provide an example for the work around you describe? I'm new to extension development so an example would be really helpful.

Comment: Or is there a way to use what I currently have, but with manifest v2?

Comment: Or can I redirect the user some other way, such as `location.href = "https://www.google.com"`? I actually tried that just now but it didn't do anything.

Comment: 1) ExtensionInstallForcelist policy. 2) There are many examples around of adding headers in declarativeNetRequest. 3) There are many ManifestV2 examples for webRequestBlocking + blocking in addListener. 4) You can do it via chrome.tabs.update(details.tabId, {url: '......'})